# Custom sort in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

We have about 8000 patient files (paper) arranged by, 1st letter of last name, 1st letter of first name, then 2nd letter of last name. So, Robert Jones's file is labeled `J,R` and would be filed After Ray Jarvis (also labeled `J,R`.)

What expressions do I need to use in my Access query to achieve this sort order? I can't seem to find a way using Microsoft help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really use Access all that much but, if I'm not mistaken, it uses VB-style string functions.  Assuming that that's true, you can use the LEFT and MID functions to extract the parts you want to sort on, e.g.

`ORDER BY LEFT(FamilyName, 1), LEFT(GivenName, 1), MID(FamilyName, 2, 1)`

I'm not sure whether MID would be 1-based or 0-based but I suspect the former.

Comment: If this has answered your question then please mark it as a valid answer.  While it seems the polite thing to do to say thank you, this site is not intended to be used that way.  If an answer is helpful then up-vote it and if it answers your question then mark it so.

Comment: I tried to up vote but it displays a message saying I need a score of 15 to allow this. I am a novice on this site.